# Get first frame of a Base64 gif in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, base64, gif, animated-gif

I am getting from back-end a list of Base64 animated gifs that I want to display in a table along with other information. I want to manually get the first frame of each gif and create a new array containing the list of 'first-frame' pngs so that i can use them later in the table. Table supports various functions like sorting, filtering, etc., so I want to have full controls over the elements displayed.

I have tried some plug ins including gifffer (https://github.com/krasimir/gifffer) and gifFrames (https://github.com/benwiley4000/gif-frames) but they either fail (browser hangs processing gif), do not support Base64 format (only URL) or change the image (the entire tag from  to ) by manipulating the dom. I want to save the first frames of each gif in an array (ideally formatted in base64)

If I let the plug in manipulate the images i get unexpected results like images retaining their position in grid despite sorting and/or disappearing when filtering table elements.